# Launching an Activity within a certain fragment, then going back to the previous Activity from where it was launched?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I've been struggling with a particular challenge which is as follows:

My app has an activity "A" which is considered the app's "main" activity. At a certain point, it launches an activity "B" which has an action available that should launch a fragment inside activity "A" (this won't always be the same fragment, it will depend on some data coming from our backend).

I can do this just fine by simply calling `startActivity` with the correct Intent, however, on pressing the back button, it goes back to A's "main fragment" (this is logic implemented inside of A's `onBackButtonPressed()`). Essentially, what should happen is as follows:

Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity A showing Fragment X -> press back -> Activity B

What happens when using `startActivity` to launch Activity A:

Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity A showing Fragment X -> press back -> Activity A showing the "main fragment". From here, if I press back again the app exits, which again is part of the implementation of A's `onBackButtonPressed`, however I've tried retrieving an `extra` from the intent which invoked A in order to conditionally bring back activity B but the Intent seemed to be empty of extras for reasons I can't figure out. I am sure I am correctly putting the extras in the Intent since activity A launches the correct fragment when invoked from B based on what I put there.

**More things I've tried:**

- Launching the desired fragment directly from within B, however this way the fragment is not shown with the navigation bar that exists in A and seems to show the main contents of activity B behind the fragment's elements, which in user experience terms is undesirable.
- Using the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag, which seemed to make no difference whatsoever.

As this is part of my company's app which already has a decent degree of complexity, I'm not at liberty to provide you with useful code samples, and hopefully my description is sufficient for someone to aid me.

**Additional information**

targetApi="n"
Testing on Android 11
Activity A has launchMode "singleTask"
Activity B has launchMode "singleTop"

Comment: Fragments can be in Activities. Activities cannot be in Fragments. So your description of the expected and actual behavior is hard to understand because you keep describing an Activity A that is "inside a fragment".

Comment: You could use an interface to communicate between activity A and A's fragments. Then in activity A you could send the extra data retrieved from the intent using the interface to any of A's fragments. Then in A's fragment you could use an if sentence inside `onBackButtonPressed()` to return to A's main fragment or to start B activity.

Comment: Anyway, I think your problem is the launch mode for Activity A. It can't have two different launch modes like you describe, but either of those modes ensures you can only have one Activity A at a time which is not what you described as your desired behavior.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I apologise, that was bad wording on my part, I understand that Fragments are part of Activities and not the other way around. I meant "Activity A showing Fragment X". I also made a mistake describing the launch modes, I will edit my question to reflect both those issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the intended behavior:

1. Avoid using any `launchMode`, `taskAffinity` or activity flags, the default behavior is absolutely good for your requirements (`"standard"` is the default launch mode). So when you do the action in Activity B, a new instance of Activity A will be launched after putting B in backstack, which is the default behavior.
2. You should have a logic in Activity A's `onBackPressed()` such that: if the fragment X is visible, then it will exit the whole activity, otherwise it passes by calling `super()`. Something like the following:

In Activity A

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("yourTagForFragmentX");
    if (fragment instanceof XFragment) {
        // The fragment is available in the fragment manager
        finish()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

For more details, [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, it seems to point me in the right direction, however I am concerned with calling `finish()` on Activity A since, as I said, it is the main backbone of the app (the vast majority of the app's functionality happens within it, with a few minor activities which pop up under specific conditions) and I am concerned with the effects of destroying it. Is there a way I could have that behaviour without the `finish()` call?

Comment: Do you understand that without the `singleTask` launch mode, there are multiple instances of ActivityA in your task stack? If you `finish()` the second one that is hosting FragmentX, it will have no effect at all on the ActivityA instance at the root of your task.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I indeed did not understand that, I appreciate the explanation which is very useful to know. I guess it's self-evident from its name.

I ultimately successfully solved my issue based on this answer and dominicoder's below. The main thing that helped was removing the "singleTask" launch mode, which allowed me to flip between activities much better. A few hours of tweaking business logic and app-specific behaviour around, and I finally have the behaviour I desired. Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating things.

1. Remove all of the launch mode flags for A and B - they should not be necessary.
2. Remove custom handling of `onBackPressed` - default handling should suffice.
3. Update A to initialize itself to the correct fragment based on the intent it's given:

---

For example:

```
onCreate(...) {
    if (getIntent().getAction() == "START_ON_X") {
        // Notice we REPLACE and DO NOT add to back stack
        getFragmentManager().replace(fragID, createXFragment()).commit()
    }
    else {
        getFragmentManager().replace(fragID, createDefaultFragment()).commit()
    }
}
```

Thus, you will have:

1. Default launcher intent launches A.
2. A launches B.
3. B launches A with specific intent to show Fragment X

This will give you a stack of A -> B -> Ax

Then when you press back, DEFAULT BEHAVIOR will leave you on B.

Then pressing back again will leave you on A.

Then pressing back again will close your app.

Again this is all standard, default behavior. KISS.